# Why does the add_student method in my Student class not work (It is saying requires additional argument but it only takes one)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a simple Student list and wish to append manual student objects created, using the method below. It comes up with an error saying it requires an additional argument.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, student_num, email, pps, middle_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.student_num = student_num
        self.email = email
        self.__pps = pps
        self.__middle_name = middle_name
        self.student_list =[]


    def get_full_details(self):
        details = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " " + str(self.student_num) + " " + self.email
        return details


    def add_student(self, student_object):
        return self.student_list.append(student_object)



# Creating 4 student objects
student1 = Student("Jimmy", "Mccarthy", 1234, "johnmc@gmail.com", 8074454, "Edward")
student2 = Student("James", "Flynn", 5678, "James@gmail.com", 7367736, "Borck")
student3 = Student("Emma", "Mcgath", 9837, "EMChammer@hotmail.com", 3455433, "Richei")
student4 = Student("Echo", "O Leary", 4334, "Echool@gmail.com", 4333357, "Wei")

Student.add_student(student1)
```

Comment: You're calling `add_student` on the _class_, not an _instance_, but haven't made it a `@classmethod`. It's unclear whether it should be called on the instance instead, made into a proper class method, or something else entirely.

Comment: What is `student_list` for? Is every student supposed to have its own list of students? Or is that supposed to be a class attribute?

Comment: i thought you mentioned that the `add_student` method is in the course class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `Student.add_student`, you need 2 arguments: `self, student_object`.
You can solve this if you first call the constructor of the class `student1 = Student("Jimmy", "Mccarthy", 1234, "johnmc@gmail.com", 8074454, "Edward")`, then use add_student on student1: `student1.add_student(Student("James", "Flynn", 5678, "James@gmail.com", 7367736, "Borck"))`.